# Minitab and output

Tags: confidence-interval, t-test, software

When you conduct a 1 sample t-test why does minitab only give an upper bound or a lower bound for a confidence interval? So if $H_0: \mu = \mu_0$ and we test $H_a: \mu < \mu_0$ or $H_a: \mu > \mu_0$ why is only an upper bound or lower bound of a confidence interval returned respectively? Whereas testing $H_a: \mu \neq \mu_0$ returns both a lower and upper bound.

Comment: Do you mean "or $H_a : \mu\geq\mu_0$"?

Comment: @Scortchi: yes i do

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the options you supply for the alternative hypothesis: "less than", "not equal", or "greater than" $\mu_0$.  If you're doing a one-sided test, Minitab assumes you're interested in a one-sided confidence interval. And it makes sense to assume that if you're interested only in testing whether the population mean's *higher* than a certain value, you'd also be interested in saying that values of the mean *lower* than a certain bound are implausible.